# How do I check if the recaptcha is working?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, captcha

I use google recaptcha on the site.
Recaptcha does not work in some countries, for example in China, in these countries I want to replace recaptcha to another captcha.
The question is, how can I know if recaptcha is available?